# how to create encrypt mount entry in /etc/mtab

Tags: encryption

I am practicing Encryption from our Community link :[FolderEncryption](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption)

But while doing `fuserunmount` command I am getting the following error.I am sure about the process . I have done as they did suggest me but I am getting this and this wasn't noticed there.

```
fusermount -u ~/visible
```

& My try information is

```
frank@august:~$ fusermount -u ~/show
fusermount: entry for /home/frank/show not found in /etc/mtab
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but I got the same error, and it went away after a restart. Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The error means `~/show` directory is not involved in mounting at the time of command (mount failed or encfs unmounted by some other action). Records in /etc/mtab created (automatically) when file system is mounted and removed after unmount.

By the way, while encfs is pretty straightforward, but it could be even more simplified by using any of the article recommended tools: *gnome-encfs* or *Gnome Encfs Manager*. They both are pretty stable and handy.